# Set Pricing Tables Same Height zurb foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation to make my site. I'm using pricing tables to define all the products. The images throw all the pricing tables to different heights. Here is the page: http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/products.html

To fix it, I have found a jQuery script that works, just not the way I need it.

Here is the jQuery

```
            <script>
    var currentTallest = 0,
         currentRowStart = 0,
         rowDivs = new Array(),
         $el,
         topPosition = 0;

     $('.pricing-table').each(function() {

       $el = $(this);
       topPostion = $el.position().top;

       if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {

         // we just came to a new row.  Set all the heights on the completed row
         for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
           rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
         }

     // set the variables for the new row
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);

   } else {

     // another div on the current row.  Add it to the list and check if it's taller
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);

  }

  // do the last row
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }

 });

    </script>
```

It adds a white block to the end of each pricing table (see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Ib5.png) I have tested this with the built in equalizer package that comes with foundation, and it does the same exact thing.

How do I make it add a white block to the description li instead of at the end of each ul?

Here are some example pricing tables if you need them as well:

```
<div class="large-8 columns">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                        <li class="title">SUP Racing T-Shirts</li>
                        <li class="bullet-item"><img src="img/product-imgs/SUP_Tees.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="description">Show your SUP Racing Pride!</li>
                        <li class="price">$18.00 + S&H</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                        <li class="title">SUP Porting for CR/500</li>
                        <li class="bullet-item"><img src="img/product-imgs/SUP_Porting.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="description">Great power and torque throughout the entire power band.</li>
                        <li class="price">$395.00 + S&H</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                  <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                        <li class="title">SUP Pipe for CR/500</li>
                        <li class="bullet-item"><img src="img/product-imgs/SUP_Pipe1.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="description">Our custom-designed pipe will give you better torque, and more useable power at a lower R.P.M.
                                                This price includes ceramic coating, silencer, flange, and front and rear mounts.</li>
                        <li class="price">$654.00 + S&H</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: If you update to Foundation 5.2 there is a new equalizer function that does exactly this. There is an example of how to use it with pricing tables in the official docs.

Comment: The equalizer function causes the same issue (white box added at end of pricing table, not in the description part of the pricing table.) This is using Foundation 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

First add the jquery.js to your page

HTML code is,

```
     <!-- Thumbnails -->

      <div class="large-8 columns">
          <div class="row container1">
              <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                <ul  class="pricing-table" >
                    <li class="title">SUP Racing T-Shirts</li>
                    <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/SUP_Tees.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="description">Show your SUP Racing Pride!</li>
                    <li class="price">$18.00 + S&H</li>
                    <div></div>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                <ul class="pricing-table">
                    <li class="title">SUP Porting for CR/500</li>
                    <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/SUP_Porting.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="description">Great power and torque throughout the entire power band.</li>
                    <li class="price">$395.00 + S&H</li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                <ul class="pricing-table">
                    <li class="title">SUP Pipe for CR/500</li>
                    <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/SUP_Pipe1.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="description">Our custom-designed pipe will give you better torque, and more useable power at a lower R.P.M.
                                            This price includes ceramic coating, silencer, flange, and front and rear mounts.</li>
                    <li class="price">$654.00 + S&H</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          <br><br>
          <div class="row container1">
            <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                <ul class="pricing-table">
                    <li class="title">Bored Mikuni TM 38mm</li>
                    <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/Bored_Mikuni.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="description">With this carburetor, you do not need the return line.
                                            If you need a carb tuning kit for your altitude, please call.</li>
                    <li class="price">$275.95 + S&H</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
              <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                <ul class="pricing-table">
                    <li class="title">V-Force Reeds</li>
                    <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/V-Force-Reeds.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="description">Description Needed...</li>
                    <li class="price">$148.95 + S&H</li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                <ul class="pricing-table">
                    <li class="title">Pro-X Piston Kits</li>
                    <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/pro-x-pistons.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="description">Description needed...</li>
                    <li class="price">$100.00 + S&H</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row container1">
                <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                        <li class="title">Vertex Piston Kits</li>
                        <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/thumbs/Vertex-Pistons.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="description">Description needed...</li>
                        <li class="price">Ceramic Coating: $190.00<br>
                                        W/O Ceramic Coating: $150.00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                        <li class="title">MSD Coils</li>
                        <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/thumbs/MSD_Coils.gif"></li>
                        <li class="description">Description needed...</li>
                        <li class="price">$61.95 + S&H</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
                    <ul class="pricing-table">
                        <li class="title">Billethead</li>
                        <li class="bullet-item"><img src="http://codywd.x10.mx/supracing/img/product-imgs/billetthead2.jpg"></li>
                        <li class="description">Description Needed...</li>
                        <li class="price">$000.00 + S&H</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
          </div>
      </div>

  <!-- End Thumbnails -->
```

And add this jquery code it will work,

```
   <script>
    function setEqualHeight(columns)
     {
         var tallestcolumn = 0;
         columns.each(
             function()
                 {

                    currentHeight = $(this).height() +160;
                    //alert(currentHeight);
                    if(currentHeight > tallestcolumn)
                        {
                         tallestcolumn  = currentHeight;
                        }
                 }
               );
        //alert(tallestcolumn);
        columns.height(tallestcolumn);
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setEqualHeight($(".container1  > div > ul"));
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It almost works, it causes the same problem as the original answer. I made it closer, changing 
    `setEqualHeight($(".container1 > div > ul"));` to 
    `setEqualHeight($(".container1  > div > ul > .description"));`

They do move the description li, but they are not equal height:
http://i.imgur.com/yvpGdMP.png

Comment: I see my problem lies in this code because it resizes all the description li's to the same height, and not all the ul's to the same height. However, I don't know how to make it make all ul's the same height, by moving the description lis, and not adding blank space at the end of the ul.

Comment: Just call the function ($(".container1 > div > ul")); with this setEqualHeight($(".container1  > div > ul > .description")); it will resize your ul as well as description

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding you, I already did that in my original comment? Using `setEqualHeight($(".container1  > div > ul > .description"));` causes this issue, where the description boxes are the same height, but the ul's no longer are. Visible here: http://i.imgur.com/yvpGdMP.png